# SAT Probability of 4...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

X _ _ X

The figure above represents four offices that will be assigned randomly to four employees, one employee per office. If Karen and Tina are two of the four employees, what is the probability that each will be assigned an office indicated an X?

I got 1/12 but the answer is 1/6. I don't understand how Karen and Tina have 4 possibilities for their positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of ways these four offices could be assigned to four people = $4\times3\times2\times1 = 24$

If Karen is in the left most and Tina is in the right most the rest of the positions could be filled by $2\times1$.If Tina is in the leftmost and Karen in the right most, again you have two ways to fill the four offices. The total number is 4. Thus the probability is $\frac{4}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Thanks

Satish

Comment: ramanthan :"If Karen is in the left most and Tina is in the right most the rest of the positions could be filled by 2×1". WOuldn't this "2x1" also include the possible positions for Tina being in the leftmost and Karen in the rightmost?

Comment: Let us say the other two employees are Mike and Lyson. With Karen in the leftmost and Tina in the right most, you KMLT,KLMT and then with Tina in the leftmost and Karen in the rightmost, you have TMLK, and TLMK.  Thus there are four ways you could have.  And without restriction, the first office could be assigned to 4, the 2nd office could be assigned to 3, the 3rd office could be assigned to 2 and the last one to the fourth.  Total ways then are 4.3.2.1 = 24.  Now divide 4/24 to get the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are $4! = 24$ possible assignments of employees to offices. We will suppose that the four employees are Karen, Tina, Alice and Bob.

The assignments of employees to offices where Karen and Tina get those offices are KABT, KBAT, TABK, and TBAK. There are four such assignments, so the probability that Karen and Tina are assigned those two offices is $\frac{4}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$.

(I think you might be forgetting that it doesn't matter which offices the other two employees are assigned to.)